# Android build.gradle - how to overwrite existing apk

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

my build file default config for outputting apks looks like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "org.myapp.cool"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode project.ext.versionSum
    def time =  Integer.parseInt(new Date().format('MMddHHmm'))
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def file = output.outputFile
            def fileName = file.name.replaceAll("^.*(?=(\\.apk))", "myandroidapp-" + time)
            output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

my issue is that im using the time stamp ( a requirement) as part of the file name.  Now if i run the app the first time its fine and the apk file(s) get created. But if i run the build again within a minute then it says the output directory could not be found and i think its because its not over writing the one thats already there for the same minute.

If i wait a few minutes then everything is fine so its a file name issue when running a build in the same minute.  How can i tell groovy to over-write a file ?

update: it seems the file does get overwritten but i keep getting this error:

local path doesn't exist
and then it says it will not build the apk since there are no changes to it. I searched Stackoverflow but the solutions im not sure help me fix the issue.  `I'm using gradle distribution 2.4 and my classpath is: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'`

Comment: Include seconds (and milliseconds) in the file name? I doubt that's the problem however. Gradle overwrites the existing APK every time you do a build.

Comment: hmmm ok thanks i'll update the question then. and i think your correct, the file does get overwritten.

Comment: Think of it this way. If the idea is for each build to be uniquely identified by a time stamp, and you are doing build > once every minute, you *need* to have second / millisecond resolution. Do you really want to simply overwrite the build if someone happens to do a second build within a minute? I'm guessing not.